# How to fill missing numbers with Null?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, recursive-query

In SQLite how to fill in null for missing numbers from a range of 1-10 when using `Group By`? I have a table called `DataTest`:

| DataID | theData |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 38 |
| 2 | 48 |
| 4 | 38 |
| 5 | 48 |
| 8 | 39 |
| 9 | 50 |
| 9 | 60 |
| 10 | 90 |

If I do `SELECT theData FROM DataTest GROUP BY dataID;` I receive :

| theData |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 48 |
| 38 |
| 48 |
| 39 |
| 60 |
| 90 |

How to alter the query to produce rows 3, 6 and 7 as below which were originally missing?

| theData |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 48 |
| null |
| 38 |
| 48 |
| null |
| null |
| 39 |
| 60 |
| 90 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query to enumerate all numbers between the lower and upper bound of the table, then computes the aggregates:

```
with recursive ids (id, maxid) as (
    select min(dataid), max(dataid) from mytable
    union all
    select id + 1, maxid from ids where id < maxid
)
select i.id, max(t.thedata) max_data
from ids i 
left join mytable t on t.dataid = i.id
group by i.id
```